# Check number of one list in another list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have 2 Lists

```
List<int> TonightsLottoNumbers = new List<int>();
List<int> MyLottoNumbers = new List<int>();
```

How can i count how many of MyLottoNumbers  exist in TonightsLottoNumbers

Comment: I think if you win you are contractually bound to share your earnings now

Comment: @Jonesy Sure, just send me your bank account information along with your name, email address, tax id number, and home address so I can give you your winnings.

Comment: You should use some `HashSet<int>` instead.

Comment: @KingKing Aren't lottery numbers ordered, rather than unordered?

Comment: im writing a simulator to see how many attempts it takes to win the lotto...

Comment: @user1438082 Some basic stats is probably going to be faster, but good luck anyway.

Comment: ah yeah but its just for fun

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MyLottoNumbers.Intersect(TonightsLottoNumbers).Count()
```

Comment: Lotto numbers generally aren't duplicated, but good point (for the general case).

Comment: @KingKing You would never have the same lottery number twice.

Comment: @gleng ah yeah, missed that.

Comment: In the event duplicates are needed, one can use a `GroupJoin` call to get them.

Comment: Servy maybe you could put that in an answer as it is technically a better solution